# How to read blank lines using %[^\n]s?

Tags: c, scanf

I am having a program where

```
fscanf(fp,"%[^\n]s",line);
```

is used for reading a line.

If I put in a while loop,

```
while(!feof(fp))
    fscanf(fp,"%[^\n]s",line);
```

the above code works for first line and for the rest, I am getting

> line as NULL. ( line = "" )

My file contains many lines even many blank lines. How can I make the above code work?

Comment: Read the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/); start with item 12.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the conversion specifier would be `%[^\n]` (no `s` on the end).

Secondly, you don't want to use the `%[` conversion specifier without an explicit size; otherwise you run the risk of a buffer overflow:

```
char line[132];
...
fscanf(fp, "%131[^\n]", line);
```

Third, this will leave the newline in the input stream, potentially fouling up the next read.

Finally, you *don't* want to use `feof` as your loop condition, since it won't return true until *after* you try to read past EOF, causing your loop to execute one too many times.

Frankly, I think the better option is to use `fgets()`; it will read everything up to and including the next newline *or* one less than the specified size.  IOW, if `line` is sized to hold 20 characters and the input line has 80 characters (including the newline), `fgets` will read 19 characters and append the 0 terminator into `line`.  If the input line is 10 characters, it will read the whole input line into `line` (including the newline).

`fgets` will return NULL on EOF or error, so you should structure your loop as

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
{
  // do something with line
}
if (feof(fp))
  // hit end of file
else
  // error on read.
```

Comment: @Joth Bode Thanks for your frank answer:-) I used fgets at last. I thought of doing some how with printf.(since I relly love to use printf). Is there any way to acheive that with printf. Answer will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that \n is not allowed within a scanset. It would be helpful if you state what you're trying to code there.

If you want to read in entire lines, I'd strongly suggest you go for the fgets() library routine. With fgets() you're able to state, how much characters to read in at max, so you're able to avoid buffer overflows.

Comment: `'\n'` _is_ allowed within a scanset as in `fscanf(stdin,"%*[^\n]");` (take from the C spec.)  True `fgets()` is better than OP's code.